# How do I break out of a map/collect and return whatever has been collected up to that point?

Tags: ruby

I'm rewriting this question in code:

```
many = 1000

# An expensive method.
#
# It returns some data or nil if no result is available.
expensive_method = lambda do
  rand(5) == 0 ? nil : "foo"
end

# Now, let's collect some data and stop collecting when no more data is
# available.

# This is concise but doesn't work.
collection = many.times.map do
  expensive_method.call || break
end

puts collection.is_a? Array # false

# This is less concise but works.
collection = []
many.times do
  collection << (expensive_method.call || break)
end

puts collection.is_a? Array # true

# My inner Rubyist ponders: Is it possible to accomplish this more concisely
# using map?
```

Comment: Will you be returning something other than `count`, or will it always be `count`?

Comment: Yes, seems I stripped down too much. Will update.

Comment: I'm not sure what the reason is to do this. If you filter what you want then do the map transform it seems like you'd accomplish the same thing in a more straight-forward manner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using `map` directly, build up your own collection and then use the fact that `break` returns a value to abort early:

```
result = 
  [0, 1, 2, 1, 0].each_with_object([]) { |val, accumulator|
    if val < 2
      accumulator << val
    else
      break accumulator
    end
  }
result  # => [0, 1]
```

If we did just `break` (instead of `break accumulator`) then `nil` would be implicitly returned and `result` would just be set to `nil`.

This solution has the advantage of only allocating a single accumulator Array and only having to loop once.

Answer (score 22):

Sure seems the only way to do this in Ruby is a filter type method then passing results to map. I'm not sure if this works in 1.8, but in 1.9 you could:

```
[0,1,2,1,0].take_while {|val| val < 2}.map(&:some_function)
```

Or in the `times` example

```
3.times.take_while {|count| count <= 1 } #=> [0,1]
```

Comment: Ooooh, you could throw `tap` in there `3.times.tap {|i| i.some_method }.take_while {|count| count <= 1}` But this doesn't seem to be any more efficient.

Comment: Oh yes. Awesome! With the updated code example above, the answer is a one liner: many.times.take_while { expensive_method.call }

Comment: Jumped the gun. It doesn't collect what's inside the block.

Comment: @hakanensari I don't follow. `[0,1,2,1,0].take_while {|val| val < 2}` returns [0,1]. Then mapping `{|val| val * 2 }` returns [0, 2]. I don't see how it doesn't collect the results

Answer (score 7):

If you really mean "up to the break", `[0,1,2,1,0]` should result in `[0,1]`, not `[0,1,1,0]`. The only way in Ruby that I know about is `break` in a loop. Functional approach could be much slower as you don't actually break:

```
r = 
  [0,1,2,1,0].inject([true, []]) do |(f, a), i|
    if f
      if i > 1
        [false, a]
      else
        [f, a << i]
      end
    else
      [f, a]
    end
  end
puts r.last.inspect
```

Compare with:

```
r = []
[0,1,2,1,0].each do |i|
  break if i > 1
  r << i
end
puts r.inspect
```

Tail recursion is out of the question for Ruby, this is how things are done in true functional languages.

Breaking `map` doesn't work for me, result is `nil`.

**Added:** As @dogenpunk pointed out, there is `take_while` (and `drop_while` in fact), which is probably a better alternative, only it always creates temporary array which may or may not be the a problem.

Comment: It does indeed seem the only way to do this is to add to an array declared outside the looping block and then break the latter when necessary. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):011:0> 3.times.select {|count| count <= 1}
=> [0, 1]
```

or

```
irb(main):014:0> 3.times.reject {|count| count > 1}
=> [0, 1]
```

Comment: perfect answer! alas, I had oversimplified my question. my apologies.

Comment: In fact it is a wrong answer. "up to the break" means `[0,1,2,1,0]` should produce `[0,1]`, not `[0,1,1,0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
3.times.map do |count|
  count > 1 ? nil : rand 
end.compact
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
odd_index = my_collection.index{|item| odd_condition(item)}
result = odd_index == 0 ? [] : my_collection[0..odd_index.to_i - 1]
```