# Return array and its' contents of map before break

Tags: arrays, ruby, mapping

Was wondering if it were at all possible to short-circuit a map and keep all of the contents of the map before breaking. Example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4].each_with_index.map { |n, i| break if i == 2;  n }

a => nil
```

Notice that the `a` variable is `nil`. I'd like for `a` to be `[1,2]`. Is this possible in Ruby without me creating an array instance and pushing the contents of this instance using `each` instead?

```
a = []

[1,2,3,4].each_with_index { |n, i| break if i == 2; a.push n }

a = [1,2]
```

Comment: You can use `select` for that. Or are you constrained to use `map`?

Comment: I didn't necessarily want to filter out and continue the loop. I wanted it to stop right then and there.

Comment: So,  you can use `each_with_object` for that `[1, 2, 3, 4].each_with_object([]).with_index { |(e, arr), i| break arr if i == 2; arr << e }`

Comment: O wow. That works lol. Feel free to post as an answer and thank you!.

Comment: It seems there's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668008/how-do-i-break-out-of-a-map-collect-and-return-whatever-has-been-collected-up-to

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks either way!

Comment: @CarlEdwards [`take_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while) will do exactly as requested (short circuit at a given condition and return an Array) e.g. `a = [1,2,3,4].take_while.with_index {|_,i| i < 2 } #=> [1,2]`. Obviously if the issue is as simple as the post itself then `take` would be a better approach `[1,2,3,4].take(2) #=> [1,2]`

Comment: Excellent! Just out of curiosity, what would be the best way to handle rescuing errors with `take_while`?

Comment: you would need to be more specific but essentially `take_while` continues until a) the block returns `false`; or b) the end of the iteration is reached so you could use that to your advantage when rescuing.

Comment: Okay cool. I think you catch my drift. Option B was what I was aiming for Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can break inside map but you can do this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4].map { |n| n if n < 2 }.compact
```

or if you want the index with it you can do this:

```
b = [1,2,3,4].each_with_index.map { |n, i| n if i < 2 }.compact
OR
b = [1,2,3,4].map.with_index { |n, i| n if i < 2 }.compact
```